# How to pass .property file to JAVA class from shell scripting?

Tags: java, unix, properties-file

How to pass `.property` file to JAVA class from shell scripting?
I am executing a `.jar` file from shell scripting. I need to pass a `.property` file (which is present in Server) to Java class. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please post the code you are trying to use in your question. It will be easier to answer.

Comment: did you mean `.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

I facing this issue and now it got solved.

```
java -Dconfig.properties.filepath=/app1/username/application/config.properties -cp "Jarname.jar:lib/*" com.xyx.packagename.methodname
```